# Calling external js function from another external js file gives "Undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have this code in plugins.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                         

watermark = function(elemId, text, hoverClass, normalClass, parentId){
    // onFocus event
    $("#"+elemId).focus(function(){
        ($(this).val()==text)
            $(this).val('');
        (parentId!=0)
            byId(parentId).className = hoverClass;
    });
    // onBlur event
    $("#"+elemId).blur(function(){
        ($(this).val()=='')
            $(this).val(text);
        (parentId!=0)
            byId(parentId).className = normalClass;
    }); 
}
});
```

Then I have this in the index.js file:

```
new watermark("footer_contact_name", "Name", "footer_form_text_active", "footer_form_text", "footer_form_field_1");
```

Everything works when written in the same js file, but when calling it like this from the index.js file, I get an undefined function error in FireFox, using Firebug to debug.

Any ideas?

Thanks

BTW: I include these in index.html like this:

```
<script src="scripts/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function after the document gets ready - wrap it in:

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `watermark` functions gets declared when the DOM is ready to be manipulated (inside `$(document).ready(function()`, therefor won't be available the moment your `index.js` gets included.

**EDIT:**

You kind of *have to* make the call to `watermark` after the DOM is ready to be manipulated, since it uses elements in the DOM. A solution would be to declare your `watermark` function outside the `$(document).ready(function()`, and then call it from `index.js` inside a `$(function() {` (shorthand for `$(document).ready()`):

functions.js:

```
watermark = function(elemId, text, hoverClass, normalClass, parentId){ 
   // function logic
}
```

index.js:

```
$(function() {
   new watermark("footer_contact_name", "Name", "footer_form_text_active", "footer_form_text", "footer_form_field_1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only defining the `watermark()` function *after* the DOM is loaded. You could define it outside the `$(document).ready()` call and you could embed the `$(document).ready()` call inside it, so it will execute when the DOM is loaded, but be available before that.

For example:

```
watermark = function(elemId, text, hoverClass, normalClass, parentId) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```